# Who created the Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lastmodifieddate, createddate

Is there the possibility to query Lightning Web Component as for every other metadata (apex class, visualforce, etc...)? 
I see them on VS Code but I cannot know the `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate` and the `LastModifiedDate`.

So, how can I know the `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate` and the `LastModifiedDate` of a LWC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate`, `LastModifiedDate` fields values of  your LWC bundle you can perform Tooling API request of the [LightningComponentBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_lightningcomponentbundle.htm)

Also, you can use your `Developer Console`, and perform SOQL query with `Tooling API`:

```sql
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate
FROM LightningComponentBundle
/* Optional filters */
```

[image: DevConsole]

Answer (score 8):

Only Aura components are exposed for querying by SOQL but LWC components are not exposed for querying (**But can query from tooling API - shown in [answer by @OlehBerehovskyi](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/278753/70823)**). However, you find both Aura and LWC in `Setup > Quick find > Lightning Components`.

Notice the **Type** column which gives info of Aura/LWC. Also you can get `CreatedBy, CreatedDate and the LastModifiedDate of a LWC`

[image]

[image]